# TypeScript: "Type is not assignable to type 'never'" with Conditional Types in Supabase Query

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, supabase, supabase-database

#### Question

I am working on a Next.js project using Supabase for the backend. I have defined some helper types to handle the responses from Supabase queries, but I'm running into a TypeScript issue that I can't seem to resolve.

##### Helper Types:

Here are my helper types and a brief description of each:

- `DbResult<T>`: This type is intended to unwrap the type from a promise. If `T` is a promise, it infers the type `U` that the promise resolves to.
- `DbResultOk<T>`: This type is meant to handle successful query results. It infers the `data` field from the promise and excludes `null` values.
- `DbResultErr`: This type is simply an alias for `PostgrestError`, intended to handle errors from the Supabase query.

```js
export type DbResult<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? U : never;
export type DbResultOk<T> = T extends PromiseLike<{ data: infer U }> ? Exclude<U, null> : never;
export type DbResultErr = PostgrestError;
```

##### Code:

I am using these types in a function that performs a Supabase query:

```js
export async function addFrequentIngresoAccion(payload: {
  // ... payload definition
}): Promise<DbResult<any>> {
  const supabase = createServerActionClient<Database>({ cookies });
  const query = supabase.from("FuenteIngreso").insert([/*...*/]).select();
  const result: DbResult<typeof query> = await query;

  if (result.error) {
    const resultErr: DbResultErr = result.error;
    return { error: resultErr };
  }

  const resultOk: DbResultOk<Tables<"FuenteIngreso">[]> = result.data as Tables<"FuenteIngreso">[];
  return { data: resultOk };
}
```

The line `const resultOk: DbResultOk<Tables<"FuenteIngreso">[]> = result.data as Tables<"FuenteIngreso">[];` is throwing the following error:

```
Type '{ CantidadIngresoRecurrente: number | null; created_at: string; es_recurrente: boolean | null; fechadepositorecurrente: string | null; fuente_name: string; id: number; LastIngresoAdded: string | null; user_id: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

I don't understand why the type is falling back to `never`. Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong here? Also, if my understanding of the helper types is incorrect, please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I literally just encountered this exact issue today... what are the odds. For me it was the return value of a Supabase Postgres Function and not a table but I think the change should be exactly what you need or close enough.

Change this line:

```
const resultOk: DbResultOk<Tables<"FuenteIngreso">[]> = result.data as Tables<"FuenteIngreso">[];
```

to this:

```
const resultOk: DbResultOk<typeof query> = result.data
```

Why this change?

DbResultOk is defined as this:

```
export type DbResultOk<T> = T extends PromiseLike<{ data: infer U }> ? Exclude<U, null> : never
```

It is similar to the DbResult definition:

```
export type DbResult<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? U : never
```

Except that generic type T is referencing the data part of the query Result object. Long story short though, it must also be `typeof query` like DbResult because T must extend PromiseLike<>.

This is part of a larger concept in TS called Conditional Types, and TS documentation about this can be found here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

Comment: Hi @roofer_chill,

Thank you for your insightful answer! Changing the line to `const resultOk: DbResultOk<typeof query> = result.data` did indeed resolve one of the issues I was facing. 

I'm still pondering over the appropriate return type for my server action. I'm considering using a conditional type like so:

```typescript
type ServerActionReturnType<T> = { data: DbResultOk<T> } | { error: DbResultErr };
```

And then having my server action return a `Promise<ServerActionReturnType<any>>`. Would you say this is a good approach?

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Honestly I'm not the best at error handling architecture, but I think it would be better to throw the DbResultErr and handle them further up the application. With that, you could just return the DbResultOk type as you are throwing the errors.